# Чому не можна вживати словосполучення «травматичне ушкодження»?

Tags: правопис, словосполучення

На просторах інтернету часто бачила невеличкі статті типу "можна і не можна вживати". Та нажаль випадок який мене цікавив був без пояснення. Тому я запитала у більш досвідчених колег.

**Пояснення вчителя**

*Вислів «травматичне ушкодження» не є коректним, адже саме слово ушкодження має на увазі травму.*

Хотілося б отримати біль детальну інформацію та декілька прикладів.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Схоже що це - медичний термін, а термінологія може мати тавтологічний вид для неспеціалістів.

У документі "[Травма хребта та спинного мозку](http://www.neurosurgery.com.ua/index.php?p=210)" даються такі означення:

> Пошкодження може бути травматичним і нетравматичним
> **Травматичне пошкодження** спинного мозку може виникнути внаслідок раптового, травмуючого удару хребта, який ламає, зміщує, руйнує або здавлює один або більше хребців. Таке враження може також бути результатом вогнепального або ножового поранення спинного мозку. Додаткове пошкодження зазвичай проявляється через кілька днів або тижнів внаслідок кровотечі, набряку, запалення і скупчення рідини в спинному мозку і навколо нього.
> **Нетравматичне пошкодження** спинного мозку може бути викликане артритом, раком, порушенням роботи кровоносних судин або кровотечею, запаленням, інфекціями або дегенеративними захворюваннями хребта.

Як бачимо - це медична класифікація пошкоджень: травматичних - що виникли внаслідок раптової зовнішньої дії ("травми"), та нетравматичних - що виникли внаслідок внутрішніх причин - захворювань, запалень, інфекцій.

Тобто "травматичне ушкодження" можна вживати у медичному контексті - наприклад як діагноз. Але у літературній мові, коли слово "травма" виступає як синонім слова "ушкодження", звичайно треба уникати таких словосполученнь.

Більше прикладів [тавтології](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) можна подивитися у Вікіпедії:

> Тавтологія (дав.-гр. ταυτολογία від дав.-гр. ταυτο — те ж саме та дав.-гр. λόγος — мова) — у риториці, використання повторювання або надлишковості у мові, коли одна частина висловлювання повністю або частково дублює зміст іншої.
>
> Тавтологію іноді вважають різновидом плеоназму, або називають «хибним плеоназмом» — тобто таким плеоназмом, який не є виправданим ані з логічної, ані з експресивної та стилістичної точки зору (наприклад, «більш тепліший» замість «тепліший», або «популярні шлягери», «відомі зірки естради», «одноголосний консенсус», «прайс-лист цін» та ін.).